# React Native Symbol(s) not found for architecture amrv7

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

The build works just fine in debug in both Android and IOS. Release for Android works fine as well. But running IOS release through XCode results in errors you can see bellow in logs.

After following these steps build fails

On fresh cloned app

```
npm install // No errors
cd ios/pod update/install // No errors
cd ../react-native run-ios // No errors runs in simulator without any problems

Bundle upp app
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios

Run vihor.xworkspace -  open XCode
In AppDelegate.m Replace line 
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
with
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

Navigate  to product/scheme/edit scheme
set Build Configuration to Release

Run Product/Clean = Success 
Run Product/Build (selected device Generic iOS Device) = Fail

(see image below) 
Generic iOS Device = Symbol(s) not found for architecture amv7
Error Linker command failed with exit code 1
```

[image: Build error]

[Package.json](https://pastebin.com/KHH0090G)

[Podfile](https://pastebin.com/a3uMSVaZ)

**Environment**
Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)
react-native-cli 2.0.1
react-native 0.57.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem was package used, react-native-ffmpeg, I used full-gpl release. But this release did not support 32bit devices. Simple update to full-gpl-lts did the trick